# systemd execute after a oneshot service

Tags: xorg

Hi is it possible to run a service after a "oneshot" type service

I want to run a script that started before display-manager.service but after gpu-manager.service, gpu-manager.service is a oneshot service that detect available gpu. This is my service :

```
[Unit]
After=gpu-manager.service
Before=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Will my service be started after gpu-manager and before display started ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need 3 services?

You can use [ExecStop or other](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) directives to run multiple scripts and use 1 systemd service.

[Try this solution](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

```bash
[Unit]
Description=example

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/on_start.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/with_stopped.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```